# Manjaro не запускается Samba

Tags: linux, администрирование, archlinux, manjaro, samba

Несколько дней вожусь, переустанавливал все пакеты, следовал советам с arch wiki и форумов manjaro, но воз и ныне там.

Конфиг Samba:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 1000
   client min protocol = SMB3_00

   server multi channel support = yes

   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *New*UNIX*password* %n\n *ReType*new*UNIX*password* %n\n *passwd:*all*authentication*tokens*updated*successfully*
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = Bad Password
   usershare allow guests = yes
   name resolve order = lmhosts bcast host wins
   security = user
   guest account = nobody
   usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershare
   usershare max shares = 100
   usershare owner only = yes
   force create mode = 0070
   force directory mode = 0070
   load printers = no
   printing = bsd
   printcap name = /dev/null
   disable spoolss = yes
   show add printer wizard = no

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[public]
  comment = Общий ресурс, в котором archie имеет доступ на запись
  path = /path/to/public
  public = yes
  read only = yes
  write list = archie
  printable = no
```

Вывод команды `sudo systemctl start samba` :

```
Job for samba.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status samba.service" and "journalctl -xeu samba.service" for details.
```

Вывод комманды `systemctl status samba.service`:

```
× samba.service - Samba AD Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/samba.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-12 23:54:42 MSK; 2min 18s ago
       Docs: man:samba(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
    Process: 12867 ExecStart=/usr/bin/samba --foreground --no-process-group $SAMBAOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 12867 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "daemon failed to start: Samba detected misconfigured 'server role' and exited. Check logs for details"
      Error: 22 (Недопустимый аргумент)
        CPU: 71ms

сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]:   daemon_status: daemon 'samba' : Starting process...
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]: [2022/09/12 23:54:42.340100,  0] ../../source4/samba/server.c:851(binary_smbd_mai>
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]:   At this time the 'samba' binary should only be used for either:
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]:   'server role = active directory domain controller' or to access the ntvfs file >
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]:   You should start smbd/nmbd/winbindd instead for domain member and standalone fi>
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]: [2022/09/12 23:54:42.340196,  0] ../../lib/util/become_daemon.c:119(exit_daemon)
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc samba[12867]:   exit_daemon: daemon failed to start: Samba detected misconfigured 'server role'>
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc systemd[1]: samba.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc systemd[1]: samba.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 12 23:54:42 demyan-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba AD Daemon.
```

Comment: А вот это смотрели? https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#SERVERROLE

Comment: @Sheridan, Да, смотрел. Также пробовал стандартные настройки для manjaro использовать

Comment: @Sheridan, с горем пополам настроил, чтоб Win10 видела мои сетевые папки. Но я не вижу ни папки с Win, ни те, что на своём же ноуте открыл (в разделе Сеть в Dolphin пусто)

Comment: Тебе надо какой-то хитрый конфиг или просто, чтобы файло шарить?

Comment: просто чтоб работало. Но вроде в manjaro-settings-samba правильный конфиг (по крайней мере testparam проходит). Но все равно Win10 может и видит сетевую папку, но подключиться не может.
Win настроена правильно, ибо когда сидел на Kubuntu, спокойно шарил файлы по samba.
А на самой manjaro не отображаются в разделе сеть файлы, что я открыл для общего доступа (в прошлых дистрах отображались)

Comment: @Sheridan, не могу понять, как заставить отображаться сетевые папки на manjaro (с вин10 больше проблем нет)

Comment: Примонтируйте то что нужно и всё.

Comment: @Sheridan, в любом случае, я не вижу папки винды

Comment: Не надо на них смотреть, просто монтируйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Избавиться от ошибки при выводе `systemctl status samba.service` помогло добавление в конфиг строки `server services = +smb`.

Чтоб в Dolphin было видно сетевые папки помогла эта статья https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Avahi